# Assign a value to a variable with DataStore fields value

Tags: extjs

I need to declare a variable TeacherName that will receive its value from the DataStore field 'NameT'

```
var storeTeacher = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                         id: 'IDstoreTeacher',
                         url: 'teacher.php',
                         method: 'POST',
                         baseParams:{task: "TEACHERNAME",
                                         parametar: idTeacher},
                         root: 'rows',
                         fields: [{name: 'NameT', type: 'string', mapping: 'teacher_name'}],
                         autoLoad: true 
});
var TeacherName = NameT;
```

But in Firebug I always get the following error message: 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: NameT is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the nameT from the store, like this:

if you want the name in the first row:

```
var TeacherName = storeTeacher.getAt(0).get('NameT');
```

if you get the error that the store is null or something else, use the code in the function load:

```
storeTeacher.load({ 
    scope: this, 
    callback: function (records, operation, success) { 
        var TeacherName = storeTeacher.getAt(0).get('NameT');
    }
});
```

Comment: In the first case I get an error message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined".

Comment: When I use "storeTeacher.load" solution, Firebug Breakpoints tells me that var TeacherName has the correct value, 
but its scope is only within the "storeTeacher.load" and can not be seen in the rest of the program. 
The error message that gives me Firebug, when I using TeacherName varaiable in program is:"Uncaught ReferenceError: TeacherName is not defined"

Comment: Declare  'var TeacherName' outside of 'storeTeacher.load'